# How to get Doctrine TEXT type?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have this annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="notes", type="string", length=65532, nullable=true)
 */
protected $notes;
```

According to this document - http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#id102 because it's less than 65535 it should be TEXT?

But the column is created as MEDIUMTEXT.

How do I fix this?

Comment: For anyone interested, the answer is: `@ORM\Column(name="notes", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)`

Comment: Add this as answer and accept it ;)

Comment: @b85411 seems to use `TEXT` if you use the above now

Comment: BTW, setting the name to notes is redundant, as it is already notes from the variable name.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are referencing not correct type in the documentation. In your code you have `type="string"` but your reference to documentation is related to `type="object"`.

If you read the part of table above in the referenced docs you will see that `string` is casted to `VARCHAR` in MySQL if `length` does not exceed the maximum length for MySQL and is casted to `MEDIUMTEXT` if `length` exceeds.

But  If you want to get explicitly `TEXT` field you will need to define your column with `type="text"` together with `length`. Depending on the defined `length` Doctrine [according to documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix) will generate one of these types:

```
+----------------------------------+-------------+
|   `length` is less or equal to   | casted type |
+----------------------------------+-------------+
| 2 ^ 8 - 1 = 255                  | TINYTEXT    |
| 2 ^ 16 - 1 = 65535               | TEXT        |
| 2 ^ 24 - 1 = 16777215            | MEDIUMTEXT  |
| 2 ^ 32 - 1 = 4294967295 or empty | LONGTEXT    |
+----------------------------------+-------------+
```

So to explicitly set type `TEXT` on MySQL you need next Annotation:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="notes", type="text", length=65535)
 */
protected $notes;
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to set the length:

```
To TINYTEXT => length = 255
To TEXT => length = 65535
To MEDIUMTEXT = 16777215
Default: LONGTEXT
```

Then, for example if you need an type text, it's necessary:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=65535)
*/
```

Comment: Length values are documented at <https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings>.