# How to change the data type of a column from STRING to TEXT in ORM Symfony 4?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have my table information defined via the annotation of the entity. So I would like to change the following column to a TEXT instead of a STRING. So I had this:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $category;
```

And I changed it to this:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $category;
```

I expected it to become a TEXT, so after migrating I checked my database and it says it's a LONGTEXT. I have no idea how this is possible, but before referting my migrations, I would like to know how to make it a TEXT and not a LONGTEXT.

EDIT: I'm looking inside the migration file and I see this:
`$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE cabinet CHANGE category category LONGTEXT NOT NULL');`

I never typed LONGTEXT so I have no clue where Doctrine is getting that from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer seems to be to give the length of TEXT as well (I thought it was defined as a fixed value), so instead of `@ORM\Column(type="text")` you should do `@ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535)`. I was able to find this answer because of this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207647/how-to-get-doctrine-text-type).

Comment: Mind that `65535` is a normal "max length" of the _row_, not the _column_. See docs for [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html) and [MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html).

Comment: @rkeet that's true, sorry if i was unclear. You deserve an upvote for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change with migrations you need notate that converting to text will base on the current column length;

```
$table = $schema->getTable("tablename");
$column = $table->getColumn("columnname");
 /** There you need set size of text that you want to use
  *  To TINYTEXT => length =  0 - 255
  *  To TEXT => length = 256 - 65535
  *  To MEDIUMTEXT = 65536 - 16777215
  **/
$column->setLength('65535');
$column->setType(Type::getType(Types::TEXT))
```

It will change current type only if current type is not been Types::TEXT. If your text is tinytext and you need to set it to text, you need first to change type to string, set length and only then set it back to text.